# What is the equivalent of DataSource for a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datasource

I'm trying to set a Listbox from a txt file. I read the file and populate a list, then I want to display it in the listbox, but I have no Datasource option available (only DataContext and DataContextChanged).

My Listbox is declared in XAML :

```
    <ListBox Name="ScriptList"  
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1"
        TextBlock.FontSize="12"
        Margin="2" />
```

Any idea why ?

Also, is it the right way to proceed (read file ->

Comment: Ok nevermind, i've used ItemsSource and it works. I tried Datasource from an example on another question here..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i've used ItemsSource and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this:

```
listbox.ItemSource = previous DataSource

listbox.DisplayMemberPath = previous ValueMember
```